# How to add Custom Attributes to QuerySets in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

consider the following models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def messages(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(user=self).order_by('-created_on')

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('account.User', related_name='message', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    data = models.TextField()
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MessageManager()
```

I want to override the QuerySet behavior for the `Message` model to include a custom method, `unread_count`:

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        unread_count = queryset.filter(read=False).count()
        print(unread_count) # this works

        # these don't work
        queryset.unread_count = unread_count
        setattr(queryset, 'unread_count', unread_count)
        #

        return queryset
```

The `messages` method works fine, and the print statement inside the manager executes, but if I try to access the `unread_count` I get an `AttributeError`:

```
>>>user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>>messages = user.messages()
2 # this is from the print statement
>>>messages.unread_count
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'unread_count'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `models.Manager`, you should be sub-classing [`models.QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods):

```
class MessageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    @property
    def unread_count(self):
        return self.filter(read=False).count()
```

Then use the [`as_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager) method in your model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = MessageQuerySet.as_manager()
```

If you need to add methods to both the `QuerySet` returned from the manager, and the manager itself, you will need to use [`from_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset):

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def some_manager_only_method(self):
        print('do stuff')

class MessageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    @property
    def unread_count(self):
        return self.filter(read=False).count()

class Message(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = MessageManager.from_queryset(MessageQuerySet)()
```